# Multiplication module which is not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, examples-counterexamples

By the definition from Barnard (1980), a multiplication module is an $R$-module $M$ in which for all submodules $N$, there exists an ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $N=IM$. Note that a cyclic $R$-module (a module generated by one element), say $\langle m\rangle$ is a multiplication module since all of its submodules, say $N$, can be written as $Im=I(Rm)$ where $I=\langle r_i\ |\ r_im\in N\rangle$.

My question is: is there any example for a non-cyclic multiplication module? I've tried some examples such as $M_{2\times1}(\mathbb Z)$ over $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb Z)$, since I thought it is non-cyclic over $\mathbb Z$, but it turns out that it is cyclic over $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb Z)$. Is there any basic example of a non-cylic multiplication module? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Two easy examples:

(1) An invertible ideal is a multiplication module.  Indeed, if $I$ is invertible  and $J \subseteq I$ then $K = I^{-1}J \subseteq R$ is an ideal and $J = IK$.  This points to any Dedekind domain which is not a PID as a source of multiplicative ideals that are not principal.

(2) Every ideal generated by idempotents is a multiplication module.  This is also easy to check.  So for example, in any infinite product of rings $\prod R_\alpha$, the ideal generated by the standard basis vectors is a multiplicative module which is not principal.